# Rounding up/down FLOATS to INTS in alphanumeric NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode12

I'm stuck on this one —

I have an alphanumeric NSString. The numbers in the string contain multiple decimals and I would like to round out those numbers to integers.

The string looks like this:
**VALUES: A:123.45678 B:34.55789 C:2.94567**

and I'm trying to use this code:
`[self log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"VALUES: %.f\n", values.toString]];`

to convert to this:
**VALUES: A:123 B:35 C:3**

Xcode offers this warning —

```
Format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'NSString *'
Replace '%.1f' with '%@'
```

I think I need a different way of "scanning" the string, identifying the numbers and doing the rounding up/down as needed, then turning that into a new string. I'm just failing miserably with every attempt.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use NSScanner! It finds numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I like NSScanner for this sort of thing. Here's a Swift solution; sorry, I'm too lazy to translate it into Objective-C, which is a little more indirect:

```
let s = "VALUES: A:123.45678 B:34.55789 C:2.94567"
let sc = Scanner(string:s)
sc.charactersToBeSkipped = nil
var arr = [String]()
while (true) {
    if let prefix = sc.scanUpToCharacters(from: .decimalDigits) {
        arr.append(prefix)
    } else { break }
    if let num = sc.scanDouble() {
        let rounded = num.rounded()
        arr.append(String(Int(rounded)))
    } else { break }
}
let result = arr.joined()
print(result) // "VALUES: A:123 B:35 C:3"
```